# Google App Engine Interactive Console: ImportError: No module named models

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a django project running on my local server under the google app engine python SDK 1.9.7.

I want to run a query in the interactive console.  I have a model called Flatpage

I put the seemingly appropriate handler in the app.yaml file, namely:

- url: /admin/.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
  login: admin

From the docs i understood that when the local development server is running the interactive console on the admin server would be running in the same environment as the a project. Yet:

the interactive console does not recognize any of my model classes and when i try to import models I get an error: ImportError: No module named models

I have tried adding the local path to the models.py file to the directory as well as various names like app.models, *appname*.models and *projectname*.models to no avail.

However. when I copy and paste the models file into the interactive console it works.

Would someone explain how to import the models file into the interactive console,

and, secondly, why the interactive console, which seemingly should already have the models defined when the server starts, needs to have the models defined again, anyway, thanks!

Comment: What's the path of `models.py`, also the snippet you're trying to run in the console would help. And try to run the same snippet in the project

Comment: Here is the snippet: import models; the path to models is /PycharmProjects/gaedjangocmsprac/cmspracapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're adding that handler to use the console locally, but what I do is use the Development Console (available since last year), which by default runs on port 8000, from there (localhost:8000/console most likely) you can import modules from your project.

For example if you have `models.py` in the same directory as `app.yaml`, you should be able to do:

```
import models

entity = models.Flatpage()
```

with no problem.

Comment: This helped a bit, importing models.py prepended with the app name does not produce an error.                    However it still fails to recognize the models, claiming Flatpage is not defined.            This also does not answer why you need to import models in the first place.

Comment: Because it's just a python console, so you need to import the modules you'll work with (like anywhere else, no magical globals). The only "special" thing about it is that the path is set to the root of your project.

Comment: That runs contrary to the docs, which say it is running in the development server environment.   And, critically, why are the models after the models.py file is apparently successfully imported?

Comment: It is running in the same environment. I guess I don't understand your question, from my point of view it works the same as any other python environment, nothing gets imported by default, some special libraries might be in the path, but you still have to explicitly import them.

Comment: By environment I mean the development server that is running simultaneously with the interactive console. This is the quote Google's sparse documentation: "The Interactive Console allows developers to enter arbitrary Python code into a web form and execute it inside their app's environment." Thus, the apps environment would seemingly have the imports already imported.

Comment: Well we are way off-topic now, but OK. You know how in Python there are no global imports (except for `__builtin__` of course), so each file you import/use/run needs its own references/imports, even if they are all in the same "environment"; whatever you type in the interactive console works just like a file, a dynamic one if you will (not exactly, just making a point, it's just a Python interactive shell). I guess you can still argue the docs are not clear enough, but IMHO, based on the language they're based on, there's no reason to assume imports (which ones anyway?) are magically there.

Comment: i don't think this is off topic; the question is why you cannot access your python app's namespace when the server is running from the interactive console as Google's docs indicate; in any case no one else seems interested.